# Estimating a light field from diffracted images

Tags: nonlinear-regression, estimators, fitting

I am a physicist, and the following problem has arisen in my research:

> Given functions $G_j:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and parameters $\alpha_j\in\mathbb{R}$, for $j=1,2,\dots, N$, find two functions $\psi,f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $$G_j(\alpha_j x + \nabla \psi(x)) \left(\alpha_j^2 + \alpha_j \text{tr}\left[\nabla^2 \psi(x)\right] + \det \left[\nabla^2 \psi(x)\right]\right) = f(x) $$ "as nearly as possible" for all $j$.

Though not important for understanding the problem, the context here is that $f$ represents the intensity of a laser beam, and $\psi$ its phase.  We send the beam through various lenses with focal lengths characterized by $\alpha_j$, and the $G_j$ are measurements of corresponding intensity patterns.  We try to infer $f$ and $\psi$ from these measurements.  Note that although I've set the domains of all functions to the entire plane, in practice we only care about a small rectangular region; feel free to assume this if it simplifies anything.

In a perfect, noiseless situation, the equations in the problem statement would be satisfied exactly, but in practice noise makes it so that there is no exact solution.  There is no particular figure of merit that I want the solution to optimize, but you can take it to be something like $$\sum_j \left\lVert G_j(\alpha_j x + \nabla \psi(x)) \left(\alpha_j^2 + \alpha_j \text{tr}\left[\nabla^2 \psi(x)\right] + \det \left[\nabla^2 \psi(x)\right]\right) - f(x) \right\rVert_2^2$$ or any similar, convenient quantity if you like.

**Question: What are techniques I can use to estimate the functions $\psi, f$?**

I know little about statistics, so any references are welcome.

One thing I've noticed about this problem is that the left hand side is independent of $f$, which makes it seem that you could estimate $\psi$ on its own by minimizing the variance of the left hand side.  If anyone can point me to methods for doing this, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Feel free to give this question a more descriptive title if that seems appropriate to anyone.  I don't know how to describe this problem to a stats audience.

Comment: Not sure, but I would start by looking into splines?Maybe you can add something about the functions $G_j$?